# Google Domain API Access Error

Tags: google-api, google-plus

i am a google apps account user. I get this error when i try to access Google Plus Domains API. "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes". The scopes that i requested for are: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly". I have been trying in vain for a long time to solve this. Can someone throw light on this?

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible the user has previously consented to an app in the same project with scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login? That scope is incompatible with the domains API, which may be causing the issue.

If this is your own user you are testing with, the easiest way might be to revoke all access to the app from your user settings, (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and seeing if you get the error then.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. removing "plus.login" scope solved it. Thanks

Comment: @ChandanReddy I am also facing same issue. Can you please explain little more how to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Nis The scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" is not compatible with Domains API. don't use it. Instead use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" scope.

Comment: @ChandanReddy Thanks :)