# Is Google plus Domains api working

Tags: google-plus-domains

I'm unable to use Google plus Domains API, even from the API explorer.
I tried to explore some methods in domains API, but I failed.
For example  `plusDomains.people.get`
give `userId` as "me".
authorized with my domain admin account.
I got the below response.

```
  403 Forbidden

    - Show headers -

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "plusDomains",
        "reason": "forbiddenScope",
        "message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
       }

  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up https://developers.google.com/+/domains/  ?

Comment: what to setup ? I'm not clear

Comment: which scope did you send with your request?  Could you post your code?

Comment: I'm not doing from the code. I'm trying it from the API explorer

Comment: the solution is here...!!<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904417/google-domain-api-access-error